# Magento 2 Layout not loading

Tags: magento2, layout

I put custom module in `app/code/`. Layout is not loading. On my custom route is blank white page. Debug showing that handles =null. This is code
**/app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="namespace\Modulename\Block\ModuleBlock" name="form" template="namespace_ModuleName::form.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
       </body>
```

**Namespace/Modulename/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
 namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     *
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**/app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Controller/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

/**
 * Contact index controller
 */
abstract class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Recipient email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'trans_email/ident_general/email';

    /**
     * Recipient email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_2 = 'contact/email/recipient_email';

    /**
     * Sender email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'contact/email/sender_email_identity';

    /**
     * Email template config path
     */
    const XML_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'custom_cats_email_template';


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        return parent::dispatch($request);
    }
}
```

**/app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

route.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="test" frontName="test" >
        <module name="Namespace_ModuleName" />
    </route>
</router>
```

Comment: namespace first letter should be capital

Comment: i wrote just for example. Thanks, i will edit it

Comment: can u please share code of `frontend/route.xml`

Comment: Already done. Maybe i have problem with permission?

Comment: Try to remove var/generation folder and try again. If still not working then please give us full code of your controller not just the execute method

Comment: The problem still exist. I update question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your module have some error, please follow below steps to have it work,

**Step1 : app/code/Test/Module/Block/Form.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Test\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Form  extends Template
{

}
?>
```

**Step2: app/code/Test/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Test\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {


         $this->_view->loadLayout();

        $this->_view->renderLayout();

    }
}
?>
```

**Step3: app/code/Test/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="module" frontName="module">
            <module name="Test_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step4: app/code/Test/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015  All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Test_Module" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

**Step4 : app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Test\Module\Block\Form" name="form" template="Test_Module::form.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
       </body>
</page>
```

**Step5: app/code/Test/Module/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**Step6: app/code/Test/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Module',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

After running **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** it will show output@url localhost/magentoce27/index.php/module/index/index

Comment: thanks, its working. Can you tell where i miss?

Comment: I will need to cross check which file I changed as When I run it was showing 404 page and then I made few changes around to have it work. You can alsways accept and upvote ans if it helped you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI it's regarded as bad practice to put ?> at the end of your php files. The reason is, if you accidentally put whitespace after the ?> then PHP will begin its response to the client. When Magento comes to set its own headers and response, it'll error, "Headers already sent" and you'll spend  hours debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

For me below code work. please try and let me know

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd" layout="1column">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Trimantra\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: for me not. I put some different modules, but have the same result - white page. But i can echo through execute() method and it displays in the browser

Comment: Please check your log file and check what exactly error you get. and update your question.